# Как задать значение данных столбца по умолчанию в pgadmin 4?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Мне надо, чтобы при добавлении новой строки в таблице, этот столбик автоматически заполнялся определенным словом.
Я видел, там есть default value в опциях столбца, но при написании почему-то выдает ошибку (на скрине показана). Уверен, что проблема решается и с помощью sql команд, но я не знаю, как. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
pgadmin 4 v2.0

Comment: Задать значение для чего? Какая ошибка?

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы при добавлении новой строки в таблице, этот столбик автоматически заполнялся определенным словом.

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу код, который вы пишите и ошибку, которая возвращается

Comment: Мне просто надо сделать значение по умолчанию для столбца надо, и никакого кода нет,у меня лишь пара столбов. Информацию обновил.

Comment: попробуйте в `Default value` написать с кавычками. `'primer'`. У вас дальше есть вкладка `sql`. Приложите с нее запрос, который генерируется

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я совсем забыл про кавычки. Напишите ответ ниже, я его отмечу верным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При указании `Default value` для строковых столбцов используйте кавычки -  `'primer'`